# How are committees in the Indian Parliament formed?

Tags: india, parliament

I came to knew that Indian parliament has various committees for various purposes. How are the members for the committees selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't been able to locate any primary documents regarding Indian committee assignments. The Indian constitution mentions committees, but not how to get assigned to them.

In most legislatures, committee assignments are done informally.  The dominant parties negotiate over who gets which assignments. They may have internal rules for this, but it's a very political (not legal) process.